# a:visited inheritance is messing up my css button

Tags: html, css, colors, stylesheet

I've currently got

```
a:visited{color: purple}
```

some where in my website which is all fine and good, but the problem is i made a css button that's also inheriting this even when I don't want it to. I tried to fix it by doing this

```
.myButton a:visited {color: #FFFFFF}
```

but it doesn't seem to make any changes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: And add the html content (not all, just the button/a tag part)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below, It will help you..

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/mUuMh/1/

```
a.myButton:visited {color: #FFFFFF}
```